# Stripe API Keeps sending requests to Webhook end-point

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier, stripe-api-php

My Stack:
laravel v10.14
PHP 8.2.7
Stripe API 2020-08-27
Laravel Cashier v14.7
spatie/laravel-stripe-webhooks 3.2

I have connected my Laravel application to Stripe via Cashier and by using the Spatie Webhook library, I am listening to some Stripe events. After I updated from Laravel 9 to 10, Whenever I update a subscription, Stripe keeps sending me these three events every second, even though the response code is 200. And it crashes the app and fills the database.

Here is an example log:
[Stripe CLI Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVecm.jpg)

Is there anything I can do to stop this? Or what might have caused this?

UPDATE:
In the job that was handling the webhook request, I was using the swap() method from Cashier. The Stripe would swap the plan and send another POST request which would create some sort of loop.

Comment: According to the Screenshot you were sharing, those are new events generated from new action made by your integration (e.g. API calls), there must be in your integrations something causing this loop of action which are triggering new events. In all cases, Stripe retries only events that weren't delivered successfully:
https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#retry-logic